# When I highlight my entry(tkinter) and press backspace, nothing happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm working on a program regarding math equations, so in my program there are tons of entries but I'm having difficulties clearing them.

For the entries I'm restricting both a character limit and I only allow number and (",") or ("."). If I type for example ' 1000 ' in my entry, then highlight it and press backspace everything works out. But as soon as I type ' 100,25 ' and add a comma into the mix. It wont delete after pressing backspace.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def validatecontent(var):
    return (var.isdigit() == bool(var)) or var == (",")  or var == (".")
vcmd = (root.register(validatecontent), '%S')

def character_limit6(var):
    if len(var.get()) > 0:
        var.set(var.get()[:6])

var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var, validate='all', 
         validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack()

var.trace("w", lambda *args: character_limit6(var))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using both a trace and a validation function? You can validate both the length and the characters just with the validation function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It seems that the problem is that it refuses to recognize a string of "," or ".", alternatively a string of numbers and "," / "." as legitimate. The following seems to work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.trace("w", lambda *args: character_limit6(var))

def validatecontent(var):
    return var.isdigit() == bool(var) or "," in var or "." in var


def character_limit6(var):
    if len(var.get()) > 0:
        var.set(var.get()[:6])


vcmd = (root.register(validatecontent), '%S')
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=var, validate='all', 
         validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey temp, but by doing so it no longer restricts the input to only numbers. And you're free to type letters also.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check for that when I tried it last time. I've come up with another potential solution for you, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In the question when you delete a selection the `var` parameter in validatecontent is a string eg. '0,0' which fails your validation routine.

Do you want to accept only valid float strings?
Are you expecting strings like '1,234.45' or '123,45'?

Below I've assumed '123,45'

Validatecontent tries to convert the string to a float after replacing any ',' with '.'.

If it can it returns true otherwise it returns True only if the string is empty.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def validatecontent(var): # Amended var is now the complete string.
    try:
        temp = var.replace(',', '.')  # Replace ','' with '.' for float conversion assumes , is decimal point.
        # temp = var.replace(',',"")  # Or replace , with empty if , is a thousands delimiter.
        fl = float(temp)
        # if temp converts to a float return length of string is less than 7
        return len(var) < 7
    except ValueError:
        return var == ""   # If it doesn't convert to a float only accept an empty string.

vcmd = (root.register(validatecontent), '%P') # '%P' passes the whole new string to validate content.
entry = Entry(root, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd) # Validate on key only.
entry.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

There may well be better validation functions involving regular expressions.  This is reasonably easy to follow though.  The entry can still be linked to a StringVar if required.  It's not required to do the validation though.